# Blazor - How do you customize InputNumber validation message for values that exceed max for that data type?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

For example, if I have an InputNumber with underlying datatype of int I want to display a message that says a number greater than int.MaxValue is not allowed. As it is currently if I were to try any number bigger than the max value for an integer I get a default message that says 'The field must be a number'. The message is not correct obviously and I want to change it. Is there a way to do that in blazor?

Comment: Did you try to use the range attribute, Something like : 
[Range(0, int.MaxValue, 
        ErrorMessage = "Your Custom message")]
    public int YourVariable;

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but it only displays the custom message for values that fall between min int value and max int value. If it falls outside of that range than it says The field must be a number. And this is is what I want to find a way to change.

Answer (score 6):

By adding ParsingErrorMessage attribute I was able to display the custom error message.

```
<InputNumber @bind-Value="anything.Age" class="form-control" ParsingErrorMessage="number out of range"></InputNumber>
```